# Animate/Tween entity in flashpunk

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, tween

So I'm new to the FlashPunk library, and don't know how to tween an Entity?
So for example how do you animate an entity's x value from the World's class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Tweens, such as the VarTween which can modify an object (or Entities) property.

For example, something like this would work;

```
var tween:VarTween = new VarTween();
tween.tween(MY_ENTITY,"x",500,2);
```

This would tween MY_ENTITY's x value to 500 pixels in 2 seconds.